# Spring JPA: assignment to transient field in @PostLoad method breaks entity removal from ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Having a simple `Entry` entity ...

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Entry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Double a;

    @Column
    private Double b;
}
```

... and a `Container` entity which holds a @ManyToMany relationship to the entries.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Container {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long container_id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Entry> entries;

    public Container() {
        entries = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void removeEntry(Entry e) {
        entries.remove(e);
    }

    public void add(Entry e) {
        entries.add(e);
    }
}
```

I'm able to remove entries from containers with the following transactional method.

```
    @Transactional
    public void deleteFromContainer(Long id, Predicate<Entry> predicate) {
        Container container = containerRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

        Set<Entry> toBeDeleted = container.getEntries().stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        toBeDeleted.forEach(entry -> container.removeEntry(entry));
        entryRepository.deleteAll(toBeDeleted);

        if (container.getEntries().isEmpty()) {
            containerRepository.delete(container);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, until I change the `Entry` entity.
By adding a transient field and a @PostLoad method which assigns a value to it, the removal is not possible anymore.

```
    @Transient
    private Double[] fields;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void setMappedFields() {
        a = fields[0];
        b = fields[1];
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void setTransientFields() {
        fields = new Double[]{a, b};
    }
```

In fact, the removeEntry() method in the `Container` class will not find a matching entry in the internally stored entries set. So the entries are not removed from the ManyToMany relationship before they are deleted by

`entryRepository.deleteAll(toBeDeleted);`

There will be following error:

```
DEBUG 12744 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from entry where id=?
TRACE 12744 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
WARN  12744 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
ERROR 12744 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKGWCV239MEJWTTQTY8LBBOYRYO: PUBLIC.CONTAINER_ENTRIES FOREIGN KEY(ENTRIES_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ENTRY(ID) (2)"
    Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKGWCV239MEJWTTQTY8LBBOYRYO: PUBLIC.CONTAINER_ENTRIES FOREIGN KEY(ENTRIES_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ENTRY(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:
    delete from entry where id=? [23503-200]
```

Although I checked with the debugger that the value to be deleted is available in the set.

Added another function to debug the behaviour. Just getting a specific `Container` from database and trying to remove the first `Entry` in it.

```
    @Transactional
    public void deleteFirstEntryFromContainer(Long id) {
        Container container = containerRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

        Set<Entry> entries = container.getEntries();

        Entry entryToBeDeleted = entries.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

        int sizeBefore = entries.size();
        boolean contains = entries.contains(entryToBeDeleted);

        entries.add(entryToBeDeleted);
        int sizeAfter = entries.size();

        HashSet<Entry> newSet = new HashSet<>(entries);
        int sizeOfNew = newSet.size();
    }
```

It turns out, that the same object instance is sometimes returning two different hashCode() values. So that I'm able to add the same instance twice to a `Set`.

I've pasted an image showing this.
[debugging results showing same instance can be added twice to a `Set`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebin6.png)

Does anyone have a hint on this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know based on which criteria elements in a hash-based set are matched against an element to add/remove? Based on the hashCode and equals method. You are not showing how you implemented equals/hashCode, but I guess you are just using what Lombok generates, which is probably not what you want. By default, Lombok generates for `@Data` annotated classes, equals and hashCode methods that are based on the whole state of the class. This is a very common beginner mistake and you will find tons of articles on this topic.
I'd suggest you avoid using Lombok alltogether and implement equals/hashCode yourself so you know what happens.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using the generated hashCode() and equals() methods from Lombok here. When I'm reducing these to just take the _id-field_ into account, then it's working fine. But I need all of the fields to be used in these methods. Most probably my findings were not clear enough in the first version of my question, so I updated it with more information.

Comment: Useful video about common pitfalls using Hibernate and Lombok: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_hEdLPDczI

Comment: Removing the `@Data` annotation is solving the problem, even without implementing dedicated equals/hashCode() methods, so using the default java implemenations from the `Object` class. @zforgo, thanks for the link to the video. Another interessting one is "Ultimate Guide to Implementing Equals & HashCode with Hibernate & JPA": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoF3RcxbVQ4